# How to get all compilation flags for current build type

Tags: cmake

CMAKE_C_FLAGS contains only common compilation flags for all build types. How can I get all compilation flags for current build type within CMakeLists.txt? So when CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is "Release" I want to get all flags from CMAKE_C_FLAGS and CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE.

Answer (score 2):

One can define new variable

```
string(TOUPPER ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE_UPPER)
```

and then use `"${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE_UPPER}}"` to get all flags for current build type.

Answer (score 0):

Within the `CMakeCache.txt`, there are also variables named after `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_<config>`:

```
cat CMakeCache.txt | ack CMAKE_C_FLAGS
CMAKE_C_FLAGS:STRING=
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=-g
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=-Os -DNDEBUG
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=-O3 -DNDEBUG
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=-O2 -g -DNDEBUG
```

Note that based on how your build system is setup, these cache variables may not list all the flag effectively used.

Comment: How can I get all flags that will be used during compilation for current build type from CMake.

Comment: Since flags can be different for every CMake targets, you will have to be more specific. It also be great if you could clarify what you mean by "during compilation".

Comment: I mean common for all targets. "During compilation" means compilator flags, not linker flags.

Comment: By "During compilation", do you mean you want to get the list of flags while the actual compilation is happening, or during the configuration of the project using CMake ?

If you want the list of flags for a specific config (or build type) during the project configuration, you could simply use the variable listed above: `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE` or `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE`.